# How the 3M Aura 9332+ masks filtrate airborne particles/virus?

Tags: fluid-filtration, diffusion

The 3M Aura 9332+ mask is labeled FFP3 which means that it filters at least 99% of airborne particles.
This [article](http://news.mit.edu/2020/gamma-radiation-found-ineffective-in-sterilizing-n95-masks-0410) mentions that N95 masks (which filtrate 95% of airborne particles) filtrate the airborne particles with some materials (wool, glass particles, and plastics...)with 1-2 percent copper and/or zinc.

I looked at the  3M Aura 9332+ [datasheet](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1194322O/aura-disposable-respirator-tds.pdf) and I couldn't find any information about their (possible) content in copper/zinc. They only mention that the filter is made of Polypropylene (cf. p2).

So my question is: if the 3M Aura 9332+ doesn't contain copper/zinc, how does it filtrate the airborne particles? Do they work like [HEPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEPA#Mechanism) with a combination of diffusion, interception, impaction, and electrostatic attraction? If yes, how is it possible because the masks are much thinner than HEPA filters?

Side question (which depend on the answer ― special pandemic): 
Can this mechanism be destroyed by humidity (breathing) and/or sweating (salty water)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about medical testing.

Comment: @SolarMike, it's not about testing but about understanding how the filtration works